# sched_setschedule fails on "aarch64-linux-musl-g++"

Tags: c++, embedded-linux, android-source, gnu, clang++

I am encountering a runtime issue with a piece of code that sets the scheduling policy on an Android. The code compiles and runs successfully using "aarch64-linux-androideabi21-clang++", but it fails at runtime when compiled with "aarch64-linux-musl-g++"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    struct sched_param param {};
    param.sched_priority = 1;
    // Set real-time scheduling policy with priority 1
    int result = sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_OTHER, &param);
    if (result == 0) {
        std::cout << "Scheduling policy set successfully.\n";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error setting scheduling policy.\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `result`?

Comment: *but it fails at runtime* -- Please be more specific.  "It fails" is not enough information.  If there are error messages, post them.

Comment: I mean by fails at run time is the result of "sched_setscheduler" is not zero, In case of the success of sched_setscheduler it prints "Scheduling policy set successfully"
fail at run time, it prints "Error setting scheduling policy"

Comment: The _value_ of result in the failing case would help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the entirety of the [musl implementation](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/sched/sched_setscheduler.c) of `sched_setscheduler` at the time of writing:

```
int sched_setscheduler(pid_t pid, int sched, const struct sched_param *param)
{
    return __syscall_ret(-ENOSYS);
}
```

It doesn't do anything, it just returns an error.